# How do I enable and disable two inputs when their respective row checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How do I enable two input boxes when their sibling checkboxes are checked and disable them when their sibling checkboxes are unchecked.

When a checkbox is checked, the updated or modified row values should be stored in these three variables `values[]` - db id (not changeable), `comp[]` - to store the component value, `plans[]` - to store the plans. When unchecked, the stored 3 values should be popped out.

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="checkRowedit">
    <td><label>220</label></td>
    <td><input name="component" type="text" value="John"></td>
    <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="9980"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="220"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="checkRowedit">
    <td><label>330</label></td>
    <td><input name="component" type="text" value="Shan"></td>
    <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="966"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="330">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="checkRowedit">
    <td><label>440</label></td>
    <td><input name="component" type="text" value="Irfan"></td>
    <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="953"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="440">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="checkRowedit">
    <td><label>550</label></td>
    <td><input name="component" type="text" value="Khalid"></td>
    <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="897"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="550">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

var values = []; 
var comp = []; 
var plans = [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of two questions, but you will want to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build your arrays after the checkbox is checked.

To enable/disable your boxes you will use the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find the `checkboxes` add events to them. When they are checked you will then disable the field and build the arrays.

```js
var values = [];
var comp = [];
var plans = [];

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]')).forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
    Array.from(checkbox.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('[type=text]'))
      .forEach(i => i.disabled = !checkbox.checked)

    // Build the arrays
    comp = getComponents()
    plans = getPlans()
    values = getValues() // requires previous two to be set

    // Test our logic
    console.log('Values: ' + values.toString())
    console.log('Comps: ' + comp.toString())
    console.log('Plans: ' + plans.toString())
  })
})

function getComponents() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name=component]'))
    .filter(item => !item.closest('tr').querySelector('[type=checkbox]').checked)
    .map(item => item.value)
}

function getPlans() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name=plans]'))
    .filter(item => !item.closest('tr').querySelector('[type=checkbox]').checked)
    .map(item => item.value)
}

function getValues() {
  return comp.reduce((arr, item, idx) => arr.concat([item, plans[idx]]), [])
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="checkRowedit">
      <td><label>220</label></td>
      <td><input name="component" type="text" value="John"></td>
      <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="9980"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="220" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkRowedit">
      <td><label>330</label></td>
      <td><input name="component" type="text" value="Shan"></td>
      <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="966"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="330" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkRowedit">
      <td><label>440</label></td>
      <td><input name="component" type="text" value="Irfan"></td>
      <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="953"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="440" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkRowedit">
      <td><label>550</label></td>
      <td><input name="component" type="text" value="Khalid"></td>
      <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="897"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="550" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yes, this works. In this when user checks the checkbox, the input should be editable and edit will be stored in those 3 array. When user unchecked, the values in the array should be vomited

Comment: I am not sure what vomited means, but I have updated the code, is this what you are now looking for?